# angularjs back previous page state.go stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, param

Hello all I want to know how to make a return to the previous page in AngularJS with state.go stateParams or between two different pages I tried this but the variable is empty:

```
   $ctrl.next = function(){

        $state.go('modiffili', {object:'test'});

    };
```

and this controller of my second page :

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

modiffiliCtrl.$inject=['$state','$stateParams'];


function modiffiliCtrl($state,$stateParams) {
    var $ctrl = this;


    console.log('modiffiliController');
    console.log($state.params.object);
   $ctrl.retour = function () {
        $state.go('^');
}
```

I can't to use rootScope.
thank you to help me !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can listen to `$stateChangeStart` event, and save the name and params of previous state in order to be able to return to it.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toStateParams, fromState, fromParams) {
   $rootScope.previousState = fromState;
   $rootScope.previousStateParams = fromParams;
});
```

And then you can call
    `$state.go($rootScope.previousState, $rootScope.previousStateParams)`
if you need it

Comment: Thank you but my boss don't want that I use rootscope :/ with ui router isn't possible with ng-click previoustate() ? or it's the only solution ? thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be afraid of using $rootScope 'just because'. It's the only place where you can be sure that every event will eventually land. I know that it's done this way in JHipster, so I think it's pretty decent solution.
On the other hand, I've found an addon to ui-router which has that feature: [REPO](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras)
[DOCS](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/previous)

Edit: Just to add, this service also uses $rootScope ;)

Comment: Just a note to future visitors, the broadcast events, like this, are now deprecated and not included in recent releases of ui-router. To use these events you must rebuild the project and include the state-events file.